# Need help to groupby day and count elements within a specified range

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

So my data looks like this at the moment:

```
DTA_ADM HOUR_AD
NUM_S       
461871  07/18/2020  52973
477090  09/23/2020  34328
2043366 10/07/2020  49953
2043366 10/24/2020  48190
1627234 07/29/2020  72266
... ... ...
421338  09/15/2020  70392
424569  05/19/2020  42863
427780  07/03/2020  44645
427780  09/05/2020  70800
2180672 09/03/2020  74661
```

And I want to count the ocorrence of a number within a specific range in the column HOUR_ADM (e.g. between 28000-50400, and 50400-86400) for each day.

Something like this:

```
DTA_ADM     INT_1     INT_2
05/01/2020  34        67
05/02/2020  59        70
05/03/2020  70        49
05/04/2020  43        35
05/05/2020  50        50
... ... ...
11/26/2020  89        65
11/27/2020  65        49
11/28/2020  64        80
11/29/2020  79        90
11/30/2020  43        65
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use `pd.cut` :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659515/python-pandas-create-groups-by-range-using-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pd.cut`:

```
rng = [28000,50400,86400]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.HOUR_AD, bins=rng)).count()
```

final solution would look like this:

```
df.groupby([df.DTA_ADM, pd.cut(df.HOUR_AD, bins=rng, labels=[f"INT_{i+1}" for i in range(len(rng)-1)])])['HOUR_AD'].agg('count').unstack()
```

---

| HOUR_AD | INT_1 | INT_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DTA_ADM |  |  |
| 2020-05-19 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-07-18 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-07-29 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-09-03 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-09-05 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-09-15 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-09-23 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-10-07 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-10-24 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: free to modify the code as per your need.